# Codeigniter is_mobile function for Google bot

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I have mobile and desktop site.If user comes from mobile I am checking it with `$this->agent->is_mobile()` method then if user is mobile I am redirecting to mobile url.It works well for mobile devices.

But I am testing my site with this tool:https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ It is not redirecting to mobile website.I think `is_mobile()` method is not returning true for google mobile bot.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$this->agent->agent_string();
```

to return the user-agent and then manually check it against the googlebot user agents; see the link below for details of the user-agents currently in use by Google Webmaster Tools:

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/references/googlebot

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, apparently if the agent is detected as robot (in that case googlebot) it won't test if it's mobile too. 
The following snippet is from the User_agent system library (line 150), look at the "break" instruction.

```
function _compile_data()
{
    $this->_set_platform();

    foreach (array('_set_robot', '_set_browser', '_set_mobile') as $function)
    {

        if ($this->$function() === TRUE)
        {
            break; 
        }
    }
```

So you either remove the "break" or you extend the library.